# Not able to create Maven Project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, maven-archetype

Not able to create maven arch project through Eclipse getting below error whenever trying to create any Maven project
 Getting this error from last 2 days.
 [image]

**Already Tried Approach** 
-Set the Proxy setting in setting.xml, proxy is working fine verified with telnet
-Recreated the local repository

Comment: Is Eclipse configured to use your `settings.xml`?

Comment: Yes, Settings.xml is configured.

Comment: Here is the snapshot of proxy setting in my settings.xml
-<proxy>

<id>optional</id>

<active>true</active>

<protocol>http</protocol>

<username>proxyusername</username>

<password>proxypassword</password>

<host>proxy.us.com</host>

<port>80</port>

<nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>

</proxy>

</proxies>

Comment: Have you tried setting a proxy in Eclipse as well? `Preferences > General > Network Connections`. I don't remember if M2 actually uses `settings.xml` when creating archetypes...

Comment: Yes Daniel I tried network connections with manual setting of proxy that also didn't helped